# Question about Elliptic integrals

Tags: numerics, special-functions

Can someone explain the following behaviour in Mathematica 12.0?

```
EllipticK[N[1/2, 100]]
```

spits out `ComplexInfinity`. However

```
EllipticK[1/2] // N[#, 100] &
```

Seems to give the correct result. In my current code, I only know the argument of the function `EllipticK` numerically, so the second option is not quite what I want.

Comment: When I evaluate `EllipticK[N[1/2, 100]]` in my copy of MMA 12, it returns `1.854074677301371918433850347195260046217598823521766905585928045056021776838119978357271861650371897`.

Comment: I can say that the both numbers are correct in version 11.2.  If you have to use numerical input insisting on exictence of such a bad issue, try e.g. `NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[1 - 1/2 Sin[t]^2], {t, 0, Pi/2}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 150, AccuracyGoal -> 100]`.

Comment: Or try `EllipticK[1/2] // FunctionExpand // N[#, 100] &` or `EllipticK[1/2] // FunctionExpand // N[#, 100] & // Chop[#, 10^-99] &`

Comment: Try `N[EliipticK[SetPrecision[x,Infinity]], 100]`, where `x` is your numeric argument. My guess for `EllipticK[N[1/2, 100]]` is a loss of precision from subtractive cancellation or underflow in the internal algorithm, but I can’t try it out right now.  What happens if you use `N[1/2, 1000]` instead?

Comment: Try restarting the Kernel. I get the numerical result for your first expression and not `ComplexInfinity` and I am using 12.0 on Windows 10.